# How can i change parent container reversed in powershell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have the need of extract all users of AD with all information about them adding a field with "parent container" field reversed

For example:

> Actual parent container field: "OU=Users,OU=Area,DC=Company,DC=com"
>
> Needed format parent container field: Company.com\Area\Users

And here the code i have right now

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | select *,@{l='Parent';e={([adsi]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)").Parent}} | export-csv \\server\folder\usersADps.csv
```

Thanks

Comment: [1] replace the final `,dc=com` with `.com` [2] split on `,dc=` [3] split the 1st part on the `ou=` [4] trim away the unwanted `,` [5] use `[array]::reverse` to reverse things [6] join them with `-join '\'`

Comment: Why not just use the canonicalname property?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PowerShell module a while back that encapsulates the functionality of the [NameTranslate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsnametranslate) and [Pathname](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadspathname) COM objects for easy use within PowerShell:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-ADName

With this module installed, you can write code like this:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*)" |
  Select-Object @{Name = "Path"; Expression = {$_.DistinguishedName | Get-ADName -Format Parent | Convert-ADName Canonical}},
  Name
```

This example uses `Select-Object` to create a [calculated property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) called `Path` that is the AD path of each object expressed in canonical name format.

Inside the `Expression =`  scriptblock (the *scriptblock* is the code within the curly `{ }` braces), this example uses:

- `$_.DistinguishedName` - this is the `DistinguishedName` property of each user passed from `Get-ADUser`
- `Get-ADName -Format Parent` - the distinguished name's parent location
- `Convert-ADName Canonical` - the parent path in canonical format

This command creates output with `Path` and `Name` properties; e.g.:

```
Path                     Name
-----------------------  ---------
myorg.local/Container A  Ken Dyer
myorg.local/Container B  Lynn Dyer
```

... etc.